# C++ - Creating reflection for primitive types

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a elegant way to create reflection for primitive types.
Say for instance that I have a `string type = "float";` Is there are way to create a float without if-statements? Perhaps using a map or something?

I've been playing around a little bit with it and I can't seem to find a good way.

I would like to map all the primitive types into a map like int, float, double etc, and simply create the type at rumtime with map[string], which could point to a function or a class or whatever.

The problem is, how am I supposed to use more than one type inside the map? Even if I use a Base class and push in templated derived classes I have to know the template type at compile time if I want to down-cast it. I'm stuck!

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

To clearify I have the size of the type, the data and the type of the data in string in a binary file, the data is serialized. I just need to find a way to automatically create the data by calling for instance `auto x = class->Create();`

and the Create function deserializes some data from a binary file. Since I already know the type, which for instance could be a float, I just need to find a way to create the data from that type, for instance:

```
decltype(map[string]()) myType; //map[string] could for instance hold a function pointer which returns a float if the string=float, or an int if string=int
memcpy(some data from binary file into myType).
```

The more I think about it seems impossible, but I'm hoping that I'm wrong.
Best regards
xx

Comment: Perhaps [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I know about it, but perhaps any other option than that would be nice, nothing wrong with boost but I would like to learn a little bit about the subject.

Comment: It sounds like you are headed in the direction of creating something very similar. You can draw inspiration from `boost::any` and create your own class, if you don't want to or are not able to use `boost`.

Comment: Say there was a way to "create a float without if-statements", then how would you actually **use** it for anything without if-statements?

Comment: You might prefer a `boost::variant` approach (a *discriminated union*, rather than `boost::any`'s RTTI-based approach) if the list of types is fixed.  Separately, what interface is actually convenient depends heavily on your answer to immibis's question above.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Please show more detailed pseudocode. Don't worry about correctness, worry about readability. `memcpy(some data into the obj which I have stored in other variables)` is totally obscure. You create an object of the type stored in the map, what you do next?

Comment: @n.m. well I return the variable hopefully and print it or whatever :) How the data will be used after that might differ from project to project. But that might be impossible since the return type of the function needs to be known at compile time...

Comment: @Mamma so you are trying to create a lib to use later, this is most probably wrong approach. Such library is possible to create but definitely not for beginners, as it is not simple for statically typed languages like C++. So again such library not easy to create and not easy to use for beginers and most probably you either have wrong approach or use wrong language.

Comment: "or whatever". So you don't really know what you will do with it. You just hope there will be some meaningful action to perform but you don't know what it will be. But suppose I know that. I want your library to print the value. Can you show me *how* you will print it?

Comment: `Is there are way to create a float without if-statements? ` Not at run-time.

Comment: @n.m. Well you got a point, this is impossible. I was hoping it would be possible to create a variable with a specific datatype at runtime and be able to return it but this would be impossible since we need to know a return type of that function at compile time.

Comment: Right. Nevertheless it is possible to achieve the effect you want in a different way. Instead of three separate things that involve an unknown type — a create function, a variable, and a print function, — you create just one gunction that creates a variable and then prints it, all inside its body, so that the type of the variable doesn't leak out.